# 3x3 matrix to produce described composite 2D transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Rotate points through 45 degrees about the point (3,7). Then calculate where the point (0,5) would now be after the transformations.

So I was able to do the first part of the problem that gives the 3x3 transformation matrix (see work below). But to do the second part of the question, would I just multiply the 3x3 transformation matrix by (0, 5, 1)? If not, how would I do it?

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 7 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2}/2 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & 0 \\
\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & -7 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

= \begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2}/2 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & 3+2\sqrt{2} \\
\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 & -\sqrt{2}/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Yes, you just multiply the individual matrices. Be sure that you get them in the right order. You should check your work, though: that final transformation matrix that you have is incorrect: it doesn’t map $(3,7)$ to itself.

Comment: @amd do I need to switch the first and third matrices?

Comment: No, you got that right. Check your multiplication.